# Variable expected with a getter in a fragment

Tags: java, android, android-fragments, getter

I have a 2 dimensions array of int in a fragment, with his getter, as follows :

```
public class AddMatriceCalc extends Fragment {

private static int [][] matriceRes = new int[MatriceActivity.n][MatriceActivity.n];

public static int[][] getMatriceResAM() {
        return matriceRes;
    }

...
```

I want to use the getter in another fragment, but it doesn't work. When I used *matriceRes* without a getter (`public static int [][] matriceRes = new int[MatriceActivity.n][MatriceActivity.n]`) it works, but when I use the getter it doesn't work :

My second fragment:

```
@Override
    public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
                             Bundle savedInstanceState) {

        View v = inflater.inflate(R.layout.add_matrice_result, container, false);

        layoutResultCalc = (LinearLayout) v.findViewById(R.id.LayoutMatriceRes);

        reloadAddMatrice = (Button) v.findViewById(R.id.reloadAddMatrice);              

        reloadAddMatrice.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {

                //ON RELANCE LA DEMANDE DE TAILLE DE MATRICE
                final Dialog matricesize = new Dialog(getContext());
                matricesize.setContentView(R.layout.dialogmatricesize);


                Button dialogbutton = (Button) matricesize.findViewById(R.id.closedialog);

                dialogbutton.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
                    @Override
                    public void onClick(View v) {
                        EditText editsizel = (EditText) matricesize.findViewById(R.id.editsizel);
                        EditText editsizeh = (EditText) matricesize.findViewById(R.id.editsizeh);
                        MatriceActivity.n = Integer.parseInt(editsizel.getText().toString());
                        MatriceActivity.m = Integer.parseInt(editsizeh.getText().toString());
                        matricesize.dismiss();

                        //MISE A ZERO DE TOUTES LES VALEURS, LES TABLEAUX, ...
                        //PUIS ON VA AU TAB CALC
                        i = 0;
                        j = 0;
                        l = 0;

                        AddMatriceCalc.getLayoutmap1AM().clear();
                        AddMatriceCalc.getLayoutmap2AM().clear();
                        AddMatriceCalc.getEdittextmap1AM().clear();
                        AddMatriceCalc.getEdittextmap2AM().clear();

                        layoutresmap.clear();
                        layoutreslist.clear();
                        textviewreslist.clear();
                        textviewresmap.clear();

                        AddMatriceCalc.getMatriceResAM() = null;

                        layoutResultCalc.removeAllViews();
                        AddMatriceCalc.getLayoutmatrice1AM().removeAllViews();
                        AddMatriceCalc.getLayoutmatrice2AM().removeAllViews();

                        AddMatriceCalc.getViewpagerAM().setCurrentItem(1);



                    }

                });

                int dialogwidth = (int) getResources().getDimension(R.dimen.width_matrice);
                int dialogheight = (int) getResources().getDimension(R.dimen.height_matrice);
                matricesize.getWindow().setLayout(dialogwidth, dialogheight);
                matricesize.setTitle("Taille des matrices");

                matricesize.show();



            }

        });

        return v;
    }
```

The line `AddMatriceCalc.getMatriceResAM() = null;`has the error **variable expected** but when I use matriceRes publicly without the getter it's ok.

Can you tell me why?

Thanks

Comment: You cannot use a getter to fetch the variable and set it to a value like what you're doing here `AddMatriceCalc.getMatriceResAM() = null`. For that, you need to use the setter method, like `AddMatriceCalc.setMatriceResAM(null);`

Comment: You trying to assign a value (null) to a get'er method.. It doesn't work like that.

Comment: why do you use a static variable/getter?

Comment: yes ok, I understand. Thank you it's a mistake